# No access to static files on AWS S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

On the django project I use Nginx to access static files placed on AWS S3. 
After successful completion of the command `collectstatic` the styles still didn't apply to the project. 
When I activate the debbugger in my browser, I can see that the requests for static files are on the right path, but they are not accessible

```
(index):18 GET https://mysite-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/static/admin/css/icons.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
(index):37 GET https://mysite-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/static/lifeline/css/global.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
(index):24 GET https://mysite-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/static/material/js/jquery.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
```

How do I access it? Do you need to change Nginx settings for this purpose?
My current nginx config

```
  location /s3/ {
      proxy_http_version     1.1;
      proxy_set_header       Connection "";
      proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
      proxy_set_header       Host mysite-staging.s3.amazonaws.com;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-server-side-encryption;
      proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
      proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      add_header             Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
      proxy_pass             https://mysite-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/;
    }
```

Comment: Are the bucket and the files publicly available?

Comment: @SándorBakos Made it public a few minutes ago. But the situation hasn't changed, maybe there is a timeout? 
But it is interesting how to set up if the account is not public, I plan to upload documents

Comment: go to the bucket and click on `static` make this folder public explicitly

Comment: It usually takes effect immediately.

Comment: This is definitely due to S3 bucket settings, not Nginx.

Comment: Thank a lot all!

Comment: do you remember how you managed to solve this, i am spinning arround with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration, removed "s3" from the location. I have this working, but still figuring out the dependency on location directive

```
location / {
proxy_http_version     1.1;
proxy_set_header       Connection "";
proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
proxy_set_header       Host mysite-staging.s3.amazonaws.com;
proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
proxy_hide_header      x-amz-server-side-encryption;
proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
add_header             Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
proxy_pass             https://mysite-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}
```